# Difference between MULE_AUTO and MANUAL in AMQP connector Mule ESB

Tags: mule, amqp, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

Do any one knows what is the exact difference between `MULE_AUTO` and `MANUAL` in ACK mode of AMQP connector ( Mule). Because I have observed that

- If ACK Mode: AMQP_AUTO -> Once the message is picked up, it is being deleted automatically
- If ACK Mode:MULE_AUTO -> Even after message picked up and delivered successfully, Message still present in Queue.
- If Ack Mode: MANUAL -> Even after message picked up and delivered successfully, Message still present in Queue.( same case like MULE_AUTO)

In MULE_AUTO and MANUAL , both the cases if we supposed to delete the message externally. What would be the exact difference. Do I missing anything.

```
<amqp:connector name="AMQP_Test" validateConnections="true"
      host="***"  ackMode="MULE_AUTO"
      username="123" password="123!" />
```

Could any one please help me out on its understanding.

Edited 2nd time:

I'm keeping ACK as `MULE_AUTO`. Message is not being deleted even after success resppnse from consumed service response. Not sure where I'm wrong
       Please find the completed config.xml.

```
<amqp:connector name="AMQP_Test" validateConnections="true" host="****"  username="123" password="123!"  ackMode="MULE_AUTO" doc:name="AMQP Connector"/>

<flow name="testrabbitmqFlow1" doc:name="testrabbitmqFlow1" >
    <amqp:inbound-endpoint queueName="amqp.test.queue" exchangeDurable="true" queueDurable="true" responseTimeout="1000000"  connector-ref="AMQP_Test"  doc:name="AMQP">
    <amqp:transaction recoverStrategy="REQUEUE" action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    </amqp:inbound-endpoint>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8085" path="test" method="POST" responseTimeout="1000000" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="value in queue .. #[payload]....#[message.inboundProperties['http.status']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Could you please let me know where exactly I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `MANUAL`, you have to manually ack (or reject) messages, as discussed here: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-transport-amqp/blob/master/GUIDE.md#manual-message-acknowledgement-and-rejection

In essence, this is done with:

```
<amqp:acknowledge-message />
```

and:

```
<amqp:reject-message requeue="true" />
```

With `MULE_AUTO`, Mule should acknowledge the messages automatically when the flow is done processing. If it doesn't do it, it must be a bug then.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have edited my question and added the complete config. This is how I'm testing a simple scenario. Could you please have a glance on my edit and suggest me.

Comment: To my actual scenario, Message shouldn't be deleted until my consuming service gives '200' response. Here even after getting success response message still present in the queue.

Comment: I have opted for 'Manual' with <amqp:acknowledge-message />. It does the required scenario as you suggested. But not sure why MULE_AUTO doesn't. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You are using transactions! You didn't mention this in the original version of the question :( That changes everything: `MULE_AUTO` is disabled when transactions are used, see: http://goo.gl/avg2ag I don't know why but for some reason the transaction doesn't commit in your flow. Maybe a bug? Do you see any transaction related entries in the logs? Running with logging at `DEBUG` level?